# Javascript class can’t construct (in Node.Js). Getting TypeError: x is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I was playing around with JavaScript
classes in Node.Js and tried out a `Rectangle` example class.
But whenever I run this code from my `index.js` file:

```js
const Rectangle = require('./Rectangle.js');

const myRectangle = new Rectangle(5,5,'1');

console.log(myRectangle.id);
```

I get this error:
`TypeError: Rectangle is not a constructor`

This is the directory tree:

```
/home_folder
————> index.js
————> Rectangle.js
```

And this is the code in `Rectangle.js` file:

```js
class Rectangle{
  height;
  width;
  identificator;
  area;
  perimeter;
  
  constructor(h, w, id, non_verbose = true){
    this.height = h;
    this.width = w;
    this.identificator = id;
    if(non-verbose == true){
      console.log('construction of ' + id+ ' done!');
    }
  }
  
  area(m = 1){
    this.area = this.height * this.width;
    if(m == 0){
      console.log(this.area);
    }else{
      return this.area;
    }
  }
  
}
```

The result I was excepting was something like this:

```
construction of rect1 done!
rect1
```

But the actual result is this:

```
TypeError: Rectangle is not a constructor.
```

I googled for solving but found nothing relevant.

Comment: It's just a typo-level error. You aren't exporting anything in `Rectangle.js`. You'd need `module.exports = Rectangle;` if you want to make it the default export (which is how you're trying to import it).

Comment: Side note: I strongly recommend using [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) in new projects (and using named exports), not the legacy CommonJS stuff. If you'd been using ESM and named exports, you'd have gotten a nice clear error (rather than a seemingly-random `undefined` value): `SyntaxError: The requested module './Rectangle.js' does not provide an export named 'Rectangle'`.

Comment: should I put `module.exports` in the Rectangle.js file or in the index?

Comment: In the file you're exporting the class from (so `Rectangle.js` I believe). You can find **lots** of examples of how to do this on the web, including right there in the Node.js documentation for [CommonJS modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (but again, I would use ESM in any new project).

Comment: do your comment as an answer @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't exporting anything in `Rectangle.js`. You'd need:

```
module.exports = Rectangle;
```

...at the end if you want to make it the default export (which is how you're trying to import it). That replaces the default value of `module.exports` (which is `{}`) with your `Rectangle` function.

---

Side note: I strongly recommend using [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) in new projects (and using named exports), not the legacy CommonJS stuff. To do that in this case, you'd:

1. Add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json` file.
2. Add `export` in front of `class Rectangle` to export it as a named export.
3. Change `const Rectangle = require('./Rectangle.js');` to `import { Rectangle } from "./Rectangle.js";`

Here's a full example —

`package.json` (of course, you'll have other things in here, but just to show the `type` setting):

```json
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

`index.js`:

```js
import { Rectangle } from "./Rectangle.js";

const myRectangle = new Rectangle(5, 5, "1");

console.log(myRectangle.id);
```

`Rectangle.js` *(I've removed some unnecessary things — no need for `area` to be a property — and fixed a couple of typo-level errors)*:

```js
export class Rectangle {
    height;
    width;
    id; // Changed from `identificator` to match your usage in `index.js`

    constructor(h, w, id, non_verbose = true) {
        this.height = h;
        this.width = w;
        this.id = id;
        if (non_verbose) { // No reason for `== true` here
            console.log("construction of " + id + " done!");
        }
    }

    area(m = 1) {
        // No need to write this to a property as far as I can tell
        const area = this.height * this.width;
        if (m == 0) {
            console.log(area);
        } else {
            return area;
        }
    }
}
```

If you'd been using ESM and named import syntax in `index.js` but you'd forgotten to export `Rectangle` in `Rectangle.js`, you'd have gotten a nice clear error (rather than an unexpected value for `Rectangle` as you did with CommonJS):

> SyntaxError: The requested module './Rectangle.js' does not provide an export named 'Rectangle'.

More about ESM [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). I also go into ESM in depth in my recent book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev) in Chapter 13.